# Integrate facebook users on Plone

Tags: facebook, plone

I'm creating a Plone site which will allow users to register with Facebook but I need more than just like boxes and feed forms.

I already have collective.simplesocial[1].

Logged users are expected to have some more data than the Plone default (i.e. height, weight, average workout...) and the data that one can get from Facebook.

So the question is: how can I register users that some data comes from Facebook? Facebook connect is quite handy since whenever the user is logged on Facebook, it will also be logged on my site.

Maybe a Plone PAS plugin? Or just prefilling the register form (though then the user will not be auto-logged with Facebook connect?).

Any help will be appreciated!

Cheers,

[1] http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.simplesocial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to comments here:

http://blog.mfabrik.com/2011/04/18/integrating-facebook-with-plone/

Martin's next book would contain related example.

Comment: Sure, that's why I mailed him asking about it, but sent me to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done some initial work on Facebook-integrated registration and login for Plone:

https://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/collective.facebooklogin

It's basically in prototype stage at this point, but feel free to branch it and extend it to meet your needs. A brief demo of the current functionality is available here:

http://www.screencast.com/users/yomatters/folders/Jing/media/4e3e8aff-1e9c-4133-ad51-ef94ad7a9927

Comment: I haven't seen any progress on the svn, are you planing to spend some more time on it?