# Authentication from multi source in Plone 4?

Tags: authentication, plone, zope

How can I authenticate user from multiple source altogether ? For example local (ZODB or ldap), facebook and openid.

Do I need to write a new PAS plugin ? Or We can achieve this the existed products ?

Comment: For facebook for example there's a few. I [already asked for it][1] some months ago.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745025/integrate-facebook-users-on-plone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to do anything.

The authentication is already done from all sources at the same time. For ex, if you configure the ldap plugin, Plone's local users can still do login.