# Get Openid Authentication Plugin return email address as identity

Tags: openid, plone, zope

Through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745025/integrate-facebook-users-on-plone) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552423/authentication-from-multi-source-in-plone-4), I've managed to integrate facebook authentication into my site.

The flow was like this:

User click on facebook login button (w/registration url) for the first time --> registration form popup and user press agree --> From then if user is login with facebook, they are automatically login into my site.

So the user can either login using email address and password as usual or login through facebook.

Can I achieve similar result with OpenId ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://www.nedproductions.biz/wiki/replacing-plones-openid-login-with-an-openid-selector-for-google-yahoo-etc

I'm aware that it's not exactly what you are searching for but it could fit your needs anyway and, after all, stackoverflow uses the same approach.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked through that. What he did is just UI related, not the openid PAS plugin though (it still return openid url at the end).