# How to authenticate with facebook account in Plone

Tags: facebook, plone, janrain

I'm searching for an existing Plone add-on that allows Facebook users to authenticate in Plone - version 4.x. There is plonesocial.auth.rpx but it's full of bugs and it doesn't work in Plone 4.

Comment: This question has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745025/integrate-facebook-users-on-plone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/RedTurtle/pas.plugins.velruse

This Plone plugin let you to enable authentication of social networks users in Plone sites, using Velruse.

Velruse is a Pyramid application so defined:

Velruse is a set of authentication routines that provide a unified way to have a website user authenticate to a variety of different identity providers and/or a variety of different authentication schemes.

It is similar in some ways to Janrain Engage with the exception of being open-source, locally installable, and easily pluggable for custom identity providers and authentication schemes.

—from Velruse documentation

Answer (score 4):

There is a fork of plonesocial.auth.rpx that works in Plone 4:  https://bitbucket.org/domruf/plonesocial.auth.rpx

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems to work. I will try to fix the minor bugs.

Comment: It would be lovely to get this properly released, I'm sure Mr. Topf (or whomever else is the original author), would be happy to let you push it out.

Comment: That link to the domruf version no longer works.  Does anyone know how to do this now?  I would also like to be able to use Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, etc., to login.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used it but I think http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.facebook.accounts/1.0b2 does what you want

Comment: It's an interesting package - thanks for sharing. However what I'm searching for is something more complex (something what plonesocial.auth.rpx was doing in Plone 3.x) - letting users authenticate in Plone with their Facebook accounts. AFAICS collective.facebook.accounts only associate Facebook account with Plone site.

Answer (score 1):

We have used the code in Martin's book to authenticate with FaceBook and it works great.

We have done some work on creating a configurable control panel instead of hardconding the facebook-app keys. You can have a look at the code at: http://github.com/codesyntax/cs.auth.facebook

We have done a similar work with Twitter: http://github.com/codesyntax/cs.auth.twitter

Comment: FWIW, "Martin's book" = "Professional Plone 4 Development: http://www.packtpub.com/professional-plone-4-development/book